# error at executing Sqlconnection.ConnectionString

Tags: c#, connection-string

I have a problem about the connection strings at web.config

below is the connection string on my web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=something\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=myDB; User Id=username; Password=password;" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

that value I stored in a static class and which recorded perfectly

but when the process at the class of my data access layer class

executing the method it got the error

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

when executing the

```
SqlConnection con = null;
con.ConnectionString = GetConnectionString();
```

the ConnectionString Method

```
public string GetConnectionString()
        {

                string connectionString = Config_Key.ConnectionString;

                return connectionString;

        }
```

it returns the exact value of connection string from web.config

I debugged those already

dunno whats wrong about it

Comment: Why do you expect `SqlConnection con = null; con.ConnectionString = ...` to work?

Comment: You set `con = null` and then proceed to try and access a property on that `null` object. You see the problem there?

Comment: Create a connection first: `IDbConnection con = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString())`. Then open it: `con.Open();`. Then use it to create an SQL command: `IDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();`. Set your query: `cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Customers";`. Then execute the command: `IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();`. Read and process the data. And don't forget to close the connection when you're done with it.